# Hangouts API: generate link to meeting

Tags: hangouts-api

I see in https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button how one can use the API to start a hangouts. However, my use case is more similar to the calendar implementation in which you create an event, and you want to save a link to a hangouts in the meeting that people can join later when the event starts.

Is that possible with this or other API?